# Easy way to convert format string to binary

Tags: c++, byte, converters

I'm curious to know if there is an easy way (ie. using clib, stl or stdlib functions) to convert a formatted (encoded?) byte string into an array of bytes (unsigned chars):

Example, formatted byte string:
**\x8C\xB5{\x00\x00**

to:
**{ 0x8C, 0xB5, 0x7B, 0x00, 0x00 }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking is **decoding** an encoded string into a plain array of chars.

To answer you question, no (AFAIK).

But can implemented quite easily.

Take a look at this.

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/decode-encoded-query-string-c

Does exactly what you aksed in 26 lines of code. Only difference a % istead of \x

Comment: Would you know of any library that might help with decoding and encoding such a format?

Comment: If you just need an ASCII decoding of strings in the format of your example just adapt the function in the link above. If you need more complex encoding/decoding just Google around for "C library decoding", "C library encoding". You'll find plenty

Answer (score 0):

Step through the string, character by character. If you see a `'\\'` character, you check if the next character is a `'x'` and then take the next one or two characters (if they are hexadecimal digits) and convert them to a byte value and add that value to the destination vector. Any other character is added to the destination as-is. Continue until the end of the string.